# VB.NET add password to ZipArchive

Tags: vb.net, zip

I have 5 files being added to a zip file via ZipArchive (System.IO.Compression) in VB.Net but I've looked all over and can't figure out how to password protect the zip file. Is this possible with ZipArchive?

Comment: try this nuget package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip

Comment: When you say that you've looked all over, doors that include the Microsoft Learn documentation? That will explain every member of that type and related types so, if it's possible, it's in there. If you don't understand what it says then that's one thing but if it's not there at all then it's not possible.

Comment: It's not there but seems like it should be a pretty basic functionality which is why I was confused and asking here